# Singleton service's init not accessible from AppComponentFactory?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin to build an Android app. I have a Service that is also a singleton. When I call `startService()` in an `Activity`, I get the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void com.mydomain.socket.SocketService.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>`

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to work with a singleton service? The reason I implemented this as a singleton is because I wanted to be able to get a reference from that service easily anywhere in my app. To implement the singleton, I simply declared my Service as `object` instead of `class`.

Comment: "I simply declared my Service as object instead of class" -- that will not work. You can either have an ordinary (non-service) `object`, or you can have a `class` that is a `Service`. Implementing a plain `Service` is rather unusual in modern Android app development -- why do you believe that you need one?

Comment: @CommonsWare I need a service to handle my socket. I need it to not shut off connection if an activity is destroyed and keep the connection for 10 minutes if the user leaves our app.

Comment: Using a service (along with wakelocks and perhaps wifilocks) to keep your socket alive is reasonable. However, a `Service` cannot be an `object` -- it needs to be a `class`, so the framework can instantiate it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the help! Is there a way to easily get a reference to my service without binding it? I wanted it to be a singleton so that I could do something like `SocketService.getInstance()` to get the instance.

Comment: Well, unless the socket lifetime is strictly tied to the service lifetime, you do not need the service to manage the socket. You need the service to *exist* and to be running to keep your process alive. However, there is nothing magical about the service actually managing the socket itself. So, if you want to keep the socket logic in an `object`, and have the service and locks be separate, you could do that. Personally, I would use Koin for dependency inversion instead of `object`, so you can more easily test the code that consumes the data from your socket manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare Great idea! I'll have a service manage the lifecycle of the socket and have the socket itself inside an Object. That way, the Service can be used as a public interface and queue up requests and what not and then pass them over to the socket.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and I found that I have declared a default constructor for the service class but did not specify it as public.

Since it is private, the AppComponentFactory class from another namespace is not able to create an instance of the service.

Add "public" to the constructor.